# Is there any theory for mathematically judging the quality of a parallel corpus before running it through a machine translation pipeline?

Tags: statistical-mt

The performance of a machine translation system is highly impacted by the parallel corpus it is trained on. Therefore, as we all know, a good quality normalized and (ideally) noise-free corpus is essential. To know how a MT system is performing we have to actually train the model first and then test its performance on the test data set. This is sometimes time consuming due to the fact that the data sets are usually huge. For my thesis I have 5 different versions of my parallel corpus. If I precisely want to measure the performance using BLEU score or some other metrics I need to train the model 5 times and that will take a lot of my time. Therefore, I was wondering if there is any way to measure the quality of a parallel corpus beforehand?
I have found [this article](http://depts.washington.edu/uwcl/nw-nlp-2010/papers/EetemadiAndRadha_Poster.pdf) which is kind of doing what I am looking for, however, I cannot cite it for my thesis as a reference since it is not a published work.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're wondering if there's any mathematical (or rather principled) manner of judging a _single_ language corpus, or a two-language corpus that is supposed to be used for translation? If the latter, well, that's the problem you're trying to solve already with MT, isn't it?

Comment: Also, yes, you can cite that article, you just have to say that it is 'unpublished manuscript' (see your bibTeX style recommendations for exactly how to put this in a citation)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's the former actually. Once I have prepared a parallel corpus, say English to Spanish, I want to 'guess' or 'predict' whether the English (or Spanish) corpus I have in my hand is going to give me good quality translation.